# Creating an AWS log group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I having issues creating an AWS log group that belongs to a bigger CloudFormation template. So just for testing, I'm creating just the log group with the following template

```
Parameters:
  LogGroupName:
    Type: String
    Description: 'cloudwatch log group name'
    Default: "test-log-group"
  LogGroupRetention:
    Type: Number
    Description: Retention period for log groups in cloudwatch
    Default: 30
  DelPolicy:
    Type: String
    Description: 'Deletion policy'
    Default: "Retain"

Resources:
  LLGO1WY:
    Type: 'AWS::Logs::LogGroup'
    Properties:
      awslogs-region: !Ref 'AWS::Region'
      LogGroupName: !Ref LogGroupName
      RetentionInDays: !Ref LogGroupRetention
      DeletionPolicy: !Ref DelPolicy
```

When I import the template during the manual stack creation ("Create Stack" button), I get the following when I get to the "Import Overview" page.

```
There was an error creating this change set
The following resources to import [LLGO1WY] must have DeletionPolicy attribute specified in the template.
```

If you look the [documentation for AWS::Logs::LogGroup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-logs-loggroup.html), it doesn't even have a `DeletionPolicy` defined as a property. Note that if I remove that property, I get the same error. Any clues?

Comment: Why are you wanting to "import" the template? That should only be used when trying to bring existing resources into a stack: [Bringing existing resources into CloudFormation management - AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AWS::Logs::LogGroup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-logs-loggroup.html) does not have `DeletionPolicy` property. [DeletionPolicy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-deletionpolicy.html) is a top level attribute which you can't parametrize.

I guess you wanted maybe:

```
Resources:
  LLGO1WY:
    Type: 'AWS::Logs::LogGroup'
    DeletionPolicy: Retain # <--- This is not property and must be here
    Properties:
      awslogs-region: !Ref 'AWS::Region'
      LogGroupName: !Ref LogGroupName
      RetentionInDays: !Ref LogGroupRetention
```

Comment: Thanks Marcin, my prototype worked so hopefully my real stack will.